# Standard deviation of a list

Tags: python, list, standard-deviation

I want to find mean and standard deviation of 1st, 2nd,... digits of several (Z) lists. For example, I have

```
A_rank=[0.8,0.4,1.2,3.7,2.6,5.8]
B_rank=[0.1,2.8,3.7,2.6,5,3.4]
C_Rank=[1.2,3.4,0.5,0.1,2.5,6.1]
# etc (up to Z_rank )...
```

Now I want to take the mean and std of `*_Rank[0]`, the mean and std of `*_Rank[1]`, etc.
(ie: mean and std of the 1st digit from all the (A..Z)_rank lists;
the mean and std of the 2nd digit from all the (A..Z)_rank lists;
the mean and std of the 3rd digit...; etc).

Answer (score 205):

Since Python 3.4 / [PEP450](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0450/) there is a [`statistics module`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html) in the standard library, which has a [method `stdev`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev) for calculating the standard deviation of iterables like yours:

```
>>> A_rank = [0.8, 0.4, 1.2, 3.7, 2.6, 5.8]
>>> import statistics
>>> statistics.stdev(A_rank)
2.0634114147853952
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that `pstddev` should probably be used instead if your list represents the entire population (i.e. the list is not a sample of a population). `stddev` is calculated using sample variance and will overestimate the population mean.

Comment: The functions are actually called [`stdev`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.stdev) and [`pstdev`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.pstdev), not using `std` for `standard` as one would expect. I couldn't edit the post as edits need to modify at least 6 chars...

Answer (score 120):

I would put `A_Rank` et al into a 2D [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/) array, and then use [`numpy.mean()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) and [`numpy.std()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) to compute the means and the standard deviations:

```
In [17]: import numpy

In [18]: arr = numpy.array([A_rank, B_rank, C_rank])

In [20]: numpy.mean(arr, axis=0)
Out[20]: 
array([ 0.7       ,  2.2       ,  1.8       ,  2.13333333,  3.36666667,
        5.1       ])

In [21]: numpy.std(arr, axis=0)
Out[21]: 
array([ 0.45460606,  1.29614814,  1.37355985,  1.50628314,  1.15566239,
        1.2083046 ])
```

Comment: the result of numpy.std is not correct. Given these values: 20,31,50,69,80 and put in Excel using STDEV.S(A1:A5) the result is 25,109 NOT 22,45.

Comment: @JimClermonts It has nothing to do with correctness. Whether or not ddof=0 (default, interprete data as population) or ddof=1 (interprete it as samples, i.e. estimate true variance) depends on what you're doing.

Comment: To further clarify @runDOSrun's point, the Excel function `STDEV.P()` and the Numpy function `std(ddof=0)` calculate the *population* sd, or *uncorrected sample* sd, whilst the Excel function `STDEV.S()` and Numpy function `std(ddof=1)` calculate the *(corrected) sample* sd, which equals sqrt(N/(N-1)) times the population sd, where N is the number of points. See more: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Corrected_sample_standard_deviation

Answer (score 55):

Here's some pure-Python code you can use to calculate the mean and standard deviation.

All code below is based on the [`statistics`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/statistics.py) module in Python 3.4+.

```
def mean(data):
    """Return the sample arithmetic mean of data."""
    n = len(data)
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('mean requires at least one data point')
    return sum(data)/n # in Python 2 use sum(data)/float(n)

def _ss(data):
    """Return sum of square deviations of sequence data."""
    c = mean(data)
    ss = sum((x-c)**2 for x in data)
    return ss

def stddev(data, ddof=0):
    """Calculates the population standard deviation
    by default; specify ddof=1 to compute the sample
    standard deviation."""
    n = len(data)
    if n < 2:
        raise ValueError('variance requires at least two data points')
    ss = _ss(data)
    pvar = ss/(n-ddof)
    return pvar**0.5
```

Note: for improved accuracy when summing floats, the `statistics` module uses a custom function `_sum` rather than the built-in `sum` which I've used in its place.

Now we have for example:

```
>>> mean([1, 2, 3])
2.0
>>> stddev([1, 2, 3]) # population standard deviation
0.816496580927726
>>> stddev([1, 2, 3], ddof=1) # sample standard deviation
0.1
```

Comment: Should it not be `pvar=ss/(n-1)` ?

Comment: @Ranjith: if you want to calculate the *sample* variance (or sample SD) you can use `n-1`. The code above is for the population SD (so there are `n` degrees of freedom).

Comment: Hello Alex,
Could you please post function for calculating sample standard deviation?
I am limited with Python2.6, so I have to relay on this function.

Comment: @VenuS: Hello, I've edited the `stddev` function so that it can calculate both sample and population standard deviations.

Comment: isnt the sample standard deviation of that list 1.0?

Answer (score 22):

In Python 2.7.1, you may calculate standard deviation using `numpy.std()` for:

- **Population std**: Just use `numpy.std()` with no additional arguments besides to your data list.
- **Sample std**: You need to pass **ddof** (i.e. Delta Degrees of Freedom) set to 1, as in the following example:

> numpy.std(< your-list >, **ddof=1**)
>
> The divisor used in calculations is **N - ddof**, where N represents the number of elements. By default ddof is zero.

It calculates sample std rather than population std.

Answer (score 15):

Using python, here are few methods:

```
import statistics as st

n = int(input())
data = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

## Approach1 - using a function

```
stdev = st.pstdev(data)
```

## Approach2: calculate variance and take square root of it

```
variance = st.pvariance(data)
devia = math.sqrt(variance)
```

## Approach3: using basic math

```
mean = sum(data)/n
variance = sum([((x - mean) ** 2) for x in X]) / n
stddev = variance ** 0.5

print("{0:0.1f}".format(stddev))
```

## Note:

- `variance` calculates variance of sample population
- `pvariance` calculates variance of entire population
- similar differences between `stdev` and `pstdev`

Answer (score 13):

In python 2.7 you can use NumPy's [`numpy.std()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html) gives the [population standard deviation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15098/sample-standard-deviation-vs-population-standard-deviation).

In Python 3.4 [`statistics.stdev()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) returns the sample standard deviation. The `pstdv()` function is the same as `numpy.std()`.

Comment: The `statistics` module accepts `int`, `float`, `Decimal` and `Fraction` -- [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) in particular could be useful if you need exact or want to alter the precision.

Answer (score 5):

pure python code:

```
from math import sqrt

def stddev(lst):
    mean = float(sum(lst)) / len(lst)
    return sqrt(float(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, map(lambda x: (x - mean) ** 2, lst))) / len(lst))
```

Comment: There's nothing 'pure' about that 1-liner. Yuck. Here's more pythonic version: `sqrt(sum((x - mean)**2 for x in lst) / len(lst))`

Answer (score 3):

The other answers cover how to do std dev in python sufficiently, but no one explains how to do the bizarre traversal you've described.

I'm going to assume A-Z is the entire population. If not see [Ome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31366254/1727470)'s answer on how to inference from a sample.

So to get the standard deviation/mean of the first digit of every list you would need something like this:

```
#standard deviation
numpy.std([A_rank[0], B_rank[0], C_rank[0], ..., Z_rank[0]])

#mean
numpy.mean([A_rank[0], B_rank[0], C_rank[0], ..., Z_rank[0]])
```

To shorten the code and generalize this to any nth digit use the following function I generated for you:

```
def getAllNthRanks(n):
    return [A_rank[n], B_rank[n], C_rank[n], D_rank[n], E_rank[n], F_rank[n], G_rank[n], H_rank[n], I_rank[n], J_rank[n], K_rank[n], L_rank[n], M_rank[n], N_rank[n], O_rank[n], P_rank[n], Q_rank[n], R_rank[n], S_rank[n], T_rank[n], U_rank[n], V_rank[n], W_rank[n], X_rank[n], Y_rank[n], Z_rank[n]]
```

Now you can simply get the stdd and mean of all the nth places from A-Z like this:

```
#standard deviation
numpy.std(getAllNthRanks(n))

#mean
numpy.mean(getAllNthRanks(n))
```

Comment: For any one interested, I generated the function using this messy one-liner: `str([chr(x)+'_rank[n]' for x in range(65,65+26)]).replace("'", "")`